# How to queue multiple requests in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, synchronous

**Description**: queue the multiple requests for ASP.NET Core 6 Web API.

There are multiple terminals/clients pc to call Web API which triggered the code which is responsible for printing to execute and send out the print command with object to be printed to a printer.

As there are many printers are available but if any one printer is in use means if one request is printing on 1 printer then other request should not proceeds and wait till first request will finish printing and then it will take another request and process for printing like this.

Do we have any suggestion for building this approach?

I have tried this approach https://michaelscodingspot.com/c-job-queues/ but its not working as while adding request in thread it will loose the this.DBContext object.

Comment: Using Async methods and awaiting async calls would be a solution, are you using async methods in your code? It would be helpful if you share your code here.

Comment: Since the web api is actually rest api and it is stateless you can't keep states of your request in your api. But you can keep state of if a printing is currently in write or not in a database or a file. Simply if you send write command to printer then you need set a flag on db/ file and set of after printing done. in between you can return 429 http response.

Comment: @EspressoCode Yes, Async we have tried but at the time of async our EF this.Context is getting null

Comment: Could you please share the relevant part of the code? Without seeing the code it is hard to comment.